# Passwords not validating correctly

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a form which uses Javascript to define starting values for labeling purposes, for cross compatibility with IE, Firefox, and Chrome. For this to work correctly the JS changes the type of the input depending on what has or has not been entered by the user.

Then I have PHP form validation which makes sure that the password adheres to the provisions that it must contain at least one number but every time I submit the form with a password which should validate, it throws up the error that my password must contain at least one number.

The relevant form input:

```
<input type="text" name="password" class="reg_pass" value="Password" 
onfocus="if (value == 'Password') { value = ''; } setAttribute('type', 'password');"
onblur="if ( value == '') { value='Password'; }
if ( value !== '' && value == 'Password') { setAttribute('type', 'text'); }" />
```

Relevant PHP validation used:

```
elseif (!preg_match("/[A-Z][a-z][0-9]+/", $password)) {

    $msg = "Password must contain at least one number";

}
```

**NOTE:**

I have used print_r($_POST) and when submitted, the password post variable displays the password that has been entered.

I've been searching for a few hours on a solution, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has this ever passed validation? Currently your regex will only accept a password with the following characteristics: 1st character must be a capital letter, 2nd character must be a lower case letter, and followed by 1 or more numbers.

Try something more like this:

```
/[A-Za-z0-9]+/
```

You could also do:

```
/[a-z0-9]+/i
```

The `i` flag gives it case-insensitivity.

If you want it to contain at least one number, you can do:

```
/\d/
```

You can run both as matches, one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex form is incorrect. I'm not entirely sure what the one you put will match, but I'm pretty sure this is the one you want:

```
\d+
```

All that does is match ANY digit (actually the `+` may not be necessary either), so if there are no matches, you can be confident that there are no numbers anywhere.